# AngularJS + route - Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL '...' cannot be created in a document

Tags: android, apache-cordova, intel-xdk, intel

Bom Dia Pessoal,

Alguém já teve o problema da aplicação XDK / cordova ficar em looping quando inicializa. Esse erro só ocorre no dispositivo.

Ela fica "reinicializando" até ocorrer o erro abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução para o problema

Inicialmente vendo essa postagem percebi onde estava o erro
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790349/angularjs-infinite-loop-with-ng-view

O problema é que meu sistema entrava em um loop infinito porque as condições da roda não eram supridas, então para solucionar o meu problema foi necessário duas ações.

1. Quando configurar a roda não usar `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
2. Quando criar a navegação usar # `<a href="#/home">Home</a>`

Reforço que isso resolveu o meu problema, pode ser que não seja usual para todos.

Segue o roteamento completo

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
   // remove o # da url
   //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

   $routeProvider

   // para a rota '/', carregaremos o template home.html e o controller 'HomeCtrl'
   .when('/', {
       templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
       controller : 'HomeCtrl',
       controllerAs : 'ctrl'
   })

   // para a rota '/sobre', carregaremos o template sobre.html e o controller 'SobreCtrl'
   .when('/sobre', {
      templateUrl : 'views/sobre.html',
      controller  : 'SobreCtrl',
      controllerAs : 'ctrl'
   })

   // para a rota '/contato', carregaremos o template contato.html e o controller 'ContatoCtrl'
   .when('/contato', {
      templateUrl : 'views/contato.html',
      controller  : 'ContatoCtrl',
      controllerAs : 'ctrl'
   })

   // caso não seja nenhum desses, redirecione para a rota '/'
   .otherwise ({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Esse é meu index.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li ng-class="{active: activetab == '/'}"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
         <li ng-class="{active: activetab == '/sobre'}"><a href="#/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
         <li ng-class="{active: activetab == '/contato'}"><a href="#/contato">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>


    <div ng-view></div>
```

Por final meus controllers

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.init = function()
    {
        console.log(Date());

        $location.replace();
    }


});

app.controller('testeCtrl', function($rootScope, $location, $scope)
{
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
    $scope.titulo = "Titulo 1";

});


app.controller('SobreCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{   
   $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
   var ctrl = this;

   ctrl.init = function()
   {
        console.log("Sobre init");
   }
});



app.controller('ContatoCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{

   $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();

   var ctrl = this;


   ctrl.init = function()
   {
        console.log("Contato init");

        if($rootScope.contatoCount ==null)
            $rootScope.contatoCount = 0;

        $rootScope.contatoCount++;
   }
});
```